# How to render array to view with drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have array `$data` in file `file.module`. I want show data it the form view.

Code:

function student_form_submit($form,&$form_submit){

```
$username = $form_submit['values']['username'];
$result =  db_query("SELECT id,username FROM  tbl_student WHERE  username LIKE  '%$username%'");
$data = array();
        while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data['id'] = $row['id'];
            $data['username'] = $row['username'];
        }
```

// In here i want render array $data to view .Please help me.

```
}
```

}

Comment: fixed code and some spelling

Comment: I just update new code.